# How to downcast properly in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, casting, private-constructor

For any reason, I have an object created by a static method which calls the private constructor. (It isn't a singleton)

I want to make a new object derives from the first one, which have more members and functions.
But it's problematic, becuase the static method returns a `firstObject*` object, so a creation with downcasting of the `secondObject*` will make a memory overflow.

What should I do? I have an access to the first object's code, but it is impossible to change its constructor (If I change it, I will have to change a huge written code).

**EDIT:**

Thank to all responders. I can change the constructor to be protected.

Comment: Posting code is better than describing it. I can't quite make out the problem out of your question as it stands.

Comment: Would marking the private constructor protected really cause that much code to have to be rewritten? Then just derive a class from that in the normal way.

Comment: Can you add a protected ctor to the class? You could then: 1. use C++11 delegating constructors, if available; or 2. extract the private ctor's functionality to a function, if possible.

Comment: If you are really getting a memory overflow, then the problem is somewhere else. Nothing in your question is related to memory overflows.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to mark it answered: either accept one correct answer, or if you don't like those, write your own and accept it.

Comment: @ereOn: You fixed his problem he forgot about you 16 mins ago and counting :).

Comment: @Gorpik: Can you explain why? I didn't try to run it, I simply knew it will cause a memory overflow, because if the `firstObject` need 100 bytes, and `secondObject` need 200 - downcasting will flow to a memory that doesn't belong to it. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Aharon A memory overflow happens when you haven't got enough memory for your application, which is not the case here. And you don't have the problem you mention either, because you are just returning a pointer and all pointers have the same size. The size of the object it points to is irrelevant because it is allocated at runtime, the compiler does not need to know it.

Comment: @Gorpik I don't understand you. The memory is allocated only when `new firstObject()` is called. If `secondObject` had a normal constructor, I create it by `new secondObject`. But I asked because it's impossible, the constructor is private. So calling to the static method will allocate `firstObject`'s memory, not `secondObject`'s. So downcasting will cause memory flow. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you intended to create a `firstObject`, but returned it through a `secondObject*` by casting with `static_cast<>`, you would get a runtime error because that cast is wrong. But nothing to do with overflows. Maybe memory corruption, but not overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your constructor is at least `protected` so that child classes can use it.

Not sure what you fear about memory overflow but this:

```
class Base {
public:
  static Base* getInstance();
  virtual ~Base() {};
protected:
  Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {};

// Implementation
Base* Base::getInstance() { return new Derived(); }

int main() {
Base::getInstance();
};
```

Works [perfectly](http://ideone.com/HiKuW7).

Now I would advise you against returning a raw pointer in that situation (`std::unique_ptr` would be way better) but that's probably off-topic.

Comment: That might not work : Base constructor is private. Would be OK if the default constructor is public. We need to see the code though.

Comment: @ereOn; are you sure that compiles? Derived cannot be created.

Comment: @ereOn Oh I see Base() is protected. Yes, that will compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not sure what the point is to repeat the same thing than the first comment, minutes after the typo was fixed in the answer.

Comment: perhaps when I posted the comment I couldn't see that any typos being fixed in the question. Besides, OP claims that the constructor is private. EDIT: in fact, I only got the edit to the question now, after posting this comment.